# Pulling summary of recently posted in topics with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have a pretty basic forum system.  The three main tables, Topic, Comment, and User have all the usual fields you would imagine such as auto-increment primary keys and foreign keys to each other, so I don't think I need to lay that all out in great detail

What I'm trying to do is get a list of the most recently posted in topics.  The list view should show the topic title, the body of the initial comment/post, and the author's name, but the list should be ordered with the topics that were most recently posted in first.

I'm not very good at MySQL beyond the most basic of queries.  I could obviously break it up into multiple queries, but I want it in one query for performance.

Here's what I came up with first, but it orders the topics according to the time of the first post.

```
SELECT topic.id as topic_id, topic.title as topic_title, topic.datePosted as datePosted, topic.views as views, topic.numComments as numComments,
    comment.ID as commentID, comment.body as body,
user.ID as userID, user.firstName, user.lastName, user.title as user_title, user.city, user.state, user.thumbnail

FROM comment INNER JOIN topic ON comment.topicID = topic.id
INNER JOIN user ON comment.userID = user.id
WHERE comment.id
        IN (
        SELECT min( comment.id )
        FROM COMMENT INNER JOIN topic ON comment.topicID = topic.id
        GROUP BY topic.id
        )

ORDER BY commentID desc';
```

Comment: I'm looking at this now.  The first thing that pops out at me is that datePosted should be a field in the comment table, not the topic table, right?  I'm assuming you want each comment timestamped, not just the timestamp of the last comment?

Comment: @burk I think @King Skuppus is right that you want post with most recent comment posted for it.

Comment: I actually had a datePosted field for both the comment and topic tables.  I realized the date for a topic could be inferred by finding the earliest comment, but I'm trying to save information rather than constantly calculate it.  I also guess I could have another field for each topic that just saves the timestamp of the most recent post, and then I wouldn't have this question.  But I'm curious how to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's my first whack at what I *think* you're asking for, a list of most recently posted comments in each topic.  Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  t.title,
  t.views,
  t.numComments,
  c.id,
  c.datePosted,
  c.body,
  u.firstName,
  u.lastName
FROM
  topic AS t
    INNER JOIN
      ( SELECT
          c_inner.topicId,
          MAX(c_inner.datePosted) AS latestPosted
        FROM
          comment AS c_inner
        GROUP BY
          c_inner.topicId ) AS cmax
      ON t.id = cmax.topicId
    INNER JOIN comment AS c
      ON c.topicId = cmax.topicId AND c.datePosted = cmax.latestPosted
    INNER JOIN user AS u
      ON c.userId = u.id
ORDER BY c.datePosted DESC;
```

If I've misunderstood what you're looking for, can you post an example of your desired results?

Comment: The latestPosted result was indeed the date/time of the last post, so I added `ORDER BY cmax.latestPosted DESC` to the very end of the query to get the topics to appear in the correct order.  However, the comment body that is being returned does not appear to be that of the body of the original post of the topic.  I hesitate to say it's random, but I'm not sure what is determining which comment gets returned for each topic.

Comment: Also, I apologize if I wasn't clear in what I was looking for.  I am trying to get a "summary view" of all the topics.  There would be a result set for each topic.  In this result set is the topic title, the initial comment, and information about the author.  These results are to be ordered by recent activity in the topic.  So the topic with the most recent comment (any comment) will appear first.

Comment: You're right, I was pulling rows from non-aggregated data.  I've done another self-join to account for that and corrected the answer above.  Give that a whirl and let me know how it works.

Comment: It's almost there.  It's returning the body of the most recently posted comment instead of the body of the original comment.  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Oh, I thought that's what you wanted.  Hmm, the original comment, eh?  Let me ponder it a few more minutes.

Comment: I hate to say this, but it's really late here, and I've got to crash for the night.  I'll take a look at it tomorrow.  I'm thinking it's probably as easy as adding another INNER JOIN to pull the earliest comment within the topic.